# Parse Background image in loginView, not fitting to fit all iPhone device screen sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I am trying to get my background image to fit all screen sizes within Parse's logInView.  Unfortunately this code isn't doing the trick I expect it to.

```
[self.logInView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Backgroundwithlogo.png"]]];
```

I have subclassed the `PFLoginViewController` to what I just called `LoginViewController`.  I have tried resizing the image that i imported, but it either adjusts itself to be too big, or too small.  The colorWithPatternImage will tile my image across the view if it's too small, and my background image seems to be stretched horizontally right now.

[image]

What I have tried:

I have tried implementing:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Backgroundwithlogo.png"]];
[self.logInView addSubview:imgView];
[self.logInView sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`
```

with no avail.  I have read the Parse Guidelines [Here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-login/iOS).  But they don't cover this issue with sizing problems inside the UI.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Backgroundwithlogo.png"];
[self.logInView addSubview:imgView];
[self.logInView sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
```

Also, you may need a specific contentMode.